# Regex named group issue

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

I have this piece of HTML:

```
</TABLE>
<HR>
<font size="+1"> Method and apparatus for re-sizing and zooming images by operating directly
     on their digital transforms
</font><BR>
```

and I am trying to capture the text inside `font` tag. This is my Regex:

```
  Regex regex = new Regex("</TABLE><HR><font size=\"+1\">(?<title>.*?)</font><BR>", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        Match match = regex.Match(data);

        string title = match.Groups["title"].Value;
```

However I get empty title. Can anybody tell me what am I missing?

Comment: A regex is the wrong tool for this. Regexes cannot parse HTML (or XML) with any degree of reliability. Use an HTML parser, and see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: @Richard: I understand this. However the website that I want to parse has a fixed structure and so I want to use Regex itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex;

```
new Regex("</TABLE><HR><font size=\"+1\">(?<title>.*?)</font><BR>"
```

isn't well formed since `+` has a distinct meaning in regex.

Based on your input string, what you want is really to have it escaped;

```
new Regex("</TABLE><HR><font size=\"\\+1\">(?<title>.*?)</font><BR>"
```

Also, if you want to match strings with newlines, you have to give a wildcard to ignore them too, so this may be even more what you're trying to do;

```
new Regex("</TABLE>.*<HR>.*<font size=\"\\+1\">(?<title>.*?)</font>.*<BR>"
```

Comment: Thanks. But didn't understand why you did .* for multiline? Wouldn't it match everything when it is RegexOptions.Singleline?

Comment: @Jack RegexOptions.Singleline only *changes the meaning of the dot (.) so it matches every character (instead of every character except \n).* In other words, you still need to match a linefeed with . or .* to ignore it.